# Mysql Query with two seperate join

Tags: mysql, join

Does anyone know the solution to this problem ?
There are 3 Tables: **orders**, **order_groups** and **stores**.
I want to list the orders, with the names of the stores where the order was placed, and where the order is going to be delivered.

I keep the `from_store_id`, and `to_store_id` in the `order_groups` table

Listing these orders would be simple, i just left join the **order_groups** to **orders**, and select the name, `from_shop_id` and `to_shop_id`, but the problem is i want the name of the stores not the id, and the store names are placed in a different table (stores)

Here is what im talking about:

```
Table orders
id  group_id    name            madeup_id
1     11        johnny cash         1
2     12        billy bob           1
```

```
LEFT JOIN order_groups on order_groups.id = orders.group_id
```

```
Table order_groups
id   from_store_id   to_store_id
11     55               56
12     56               55
```

```
Table stores
id    store_name
55     thisstore
56     thatstore
```

```
The result im looking for is:
   name         from_store   to_store
1.johhny cash   thisstore, thatstore
2.billy bob     thatstore, thisstore
```

The statement i have yet:

```
SELECT 
orders.name, something as from_store, something as to_store
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN order_groups on order_groups.id = orders.group_id

somehow join stores on the order_groups.from_store_id = stores.id

WHERE orders.madeup_id = 1
```

Any idea how to select and join the store names to the query ?

One more question. I actually want to list two kind of orders in one query from different tables too, im on the right track with this structure ?

```
SELECT a,b FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON b.something=a.something WHERE something 
UNION ALL
SELECT a,b FROM c LEFT JOIN c ON c.something=a.something WHERE something
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to join 2 times the same table!

```
SELECT 
orders.name, fromStore.store_name as from_store, toStore.store_name as to_store
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN order_groups on order_groups.id = orders.group_id
left join stores fromStore on the order_groups.from_store_id = fromStore.id
left join stores toStore on the order_groups.to_store_id = toStore.id
WHERE orders.madeup_id = 1
```

Comment: thank you DanB, i didnt know i can do that with join. Perfect answer !